# Why my module is not published in modules folder?

Tags: php, laravel-8

PS C:\wamp64\www\mapini> php artisan vendor:publish

Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish?:
[0 ] Publish files from all providers and tags listed below
[37] Provider: TypiCMS\Modules\Slides\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider

> 37

Copied Directory [\vendor\typicms\slides\resources\views] To [\resources\views\vendor\slides]
Copied Directory [\vendor\typicms\slides\resources\scss] To [\resources\scss]
Publishing complete.

Comment: I have already put TypiCMS\Modules\Slides\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider before TypiCMS\Modules\Core\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider in config/app.php.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.